# Why doesn't the C language have subrange type as Pascal does?

Tags: c

Why does the **C** language have an enum type but not a range type as Pascal does?
In Pascal we write this: `type index = 1...100;` or like this:
`type letter = 'a'...'z';`.

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for? Do you want the inventors of C to come in and explain their choices?

Comment: Because C is a *different language* than Pascal.

Comment: Consider being part of the C standard committee and propose it. Hint: it is several years of full time job (and you'll need to make a prototype implementation, e.g. some experimental variant of GCC, and demonstrate that most existing C code compile on that).

Comment: @melpomene, I just stucked with this question on exam , and don't know how could I answer this

Comment: Because Dennis Ritchie != Niklaus Wirth, and didn't have his decade's worth of experience in language design. It is unclear what kind of an answer would satisfy you here, or the examiners. Terrible question. You should complain. Even if it's been taught, the answer is entirely opinion-based.

Comment: What exam? With this question?

Comment: @DeiDei,yes , with this

Comment: Terrible exam question. It's like a kids question: "Why Daddy? Why?"

Comment: One thing, `type letter = 'a'...'z';` would not be portable C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The designers of the C language implemented a very simple language whose features were only those that  could be (for the most part) directly translated into to one or a handful of machine-code instructions. Anything that could not be done easily by the CPU had to be provided by a function call.

This makes the compiler very easy to write and also ensures that it is easier to see where performance problems might be.

Implementing a range takes several machine code instructions. Also, if it is used as a type qualifier it means that range checking has to be added to all arithmetic operations which requires further machine code instructions.

There are a lot of other constructs that are supported by other languages that are not supported in C except through function calls (dynamic memory allocation, string manipulation, maps, etc).